# what is Environment <none> in a kubectl describe pod command

Tags: kubernetes

When I do a  `kubectl describe pod`, I can see

```
Environment:                <none>
```

just after secrets. I wonder what it is. Is it possible to assign secrets to an environment? ( local, dev, staging, prod for instance ? )

```
➜  espace-client git:(master) ✗ kubectl describe pod -n espace-client espace-client-client-6b7b994b4c-gx58t 
Name:           espace-client-client-6b7b994b4c-gx58t
Namespace:      espace-client
Priority:       0
Node:           minikube/192.168.0.85
Start Time:     Fri, 27 Sep 2019 11:37:06 +0200
Labels:         app=espace-client-client
                pod-template-hash=6b7b994b4c
Annotations:    kubectl.kubernetes.io/restartedAt: 2019-09-27T11:37:06+02:00
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.21
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/espace-client-client-6b7b994b4c
Containers:
  espace-client-client:
    Container ID:   docker://b3ee1efe45bb8ed9f27aca60e3bfecc1d7e29bc12600787d8d674ffb62ffc3f4
    Image:          espace_client_client:local
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:4cf73af7615ebfd30e7a8b0126154fa12b605dd34ead7cb0eefc43cd3ccc869b
    Port:           3000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 27 Sep 2019 11:37:09 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment Variables from:
      espace-client-client-env  Secret  Optional: false
    Environment:                <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-lzb8h (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-lzb8h:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-lzb8h
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment section contains any environment variables defined as part of the PodSpec:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envar-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-envars
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envar-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
    - name: DEMO_GREETING
      value: "Hello from the environment"
    - name: DEMO_FAREWELL
      value: "Such a sweet sorrow"
```

It is  because most likely no Env vars where defined for the Pod. You can also assign [Secrets to environment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables). They would show up in the Environment section like this:

`SECURITY_JWT_PRIVATEKEY: <set to the key 'privateKey' in secret 'tokens'> Optional: false`

For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secrets-demo
  labels:
    purpose: demonstrate-secrets-in-env
spec:
  containers:
  - name: secret-demo-container
    image: gcr.io/google-samples/node-hello:1.0
    env:
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: password
```